# Div blinking border on colored background

Tags: css, border

How to make the div border blink, by changing the border color to black and white can be done, but I later decided to keep the background color pink, so white border would be seen, which should not be, by dynamically adding the border and removing it, it disturbs the position of its neighboring elements, Is there anything like making the border black and transparent, alternatively, to make it blink???

Comment: @unor, thnx a lot, it worked...

Answer (score 2):

First off, animated web-page elements, especially those that alternate between colors are huge design no-no - it distracts the user, might trigger epilepsy (if used excessively), slows down page rendering performance (and drains device batteries unnecessarily), and other undesirable side-effects.

But anyway...

You can have an invisible border by setting the `border-color` to `transparent` before changing it to black or white or whatever. That way the border is there when the box flow is computed, it just isn't visible. This is a CSS2+ feature.

An alternative is to use image-borders and set the border image to an animated GIF. This does require CSS3 support for image borders.

Comment: Here is the [CSS 2.1 specification of `border-color`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#border-color-properties).

Comment: @Dai, can u just post a link for the example code or so for the "border images??"!!!